# How to get ion-radio value in vue js - ionic

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am using `ionic` framework in `vuejs`.

I have created a product page but it does not contain any form in it.

There is a radio button in the page which contains **size** of the product.

How can I access the selected value of the radio button created with `ion-radio`
when `add to cart` button is pressed from that page.

I am new to `vue.js`. Usually I used to get the value in jQuery using following method:

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked').val()
```

How can I get the selected radio button value in `vuejs`???

Here is the html part:

```
<ion-list v-if="product.size_maps">
  <ion-radio-group>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col
        v-for="size in product.size_maps"
        :key="size.id"
        size="6"
        id="product_size"
      >
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="ion-no-margin">
            {{ size.size.text }}
          </ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" :value="size.size.id"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

I have created a method called `addToCart`:

```
  methods: {
    addToCart(event) {
      console.log(event);
      // get radio button value here
    }
  }
```

Here is how I called the addToCart function in the button

```
<ion-button
  color="primary"
  fill="solid"
  expand="block"
  size="default"
  v-on:click="addToCart"
>
  Add To Cart
</ion-button>
```

**Edit:**

I tried to use `v-model` to get the data. but since there is no `input` tag available I could not add that.

If I added the `v-model` in `ion-radio` tag then all the radio buttons are being checked

Comment: I don't know ionic, but generally in vue2, you should bind data() property to input's v-model like [other frameworks do](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio). Otherwise you can try @ionSelect or similar event listener, but it is workaround, not a proper solution.

Comment: @bigless If i use `v-model` in the `ion-radio` i see that all the radio buttons are checked :(

Comment: check using `ionChange` in `ion-radio-group`

Comment: Isn't `:value="size.size.id"` your value?

Comment: @AjitPanigrahi it is not the selected value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured that `v-model` will only work if you add `v-model` in `ion-radio-group` not in `ion-radio`.

**Here is the solution:**

*add `v-model` in `ion-radio-group`*

```
<ion-list v-if="product.size_maps">
  <ion-radio-group v-model="selected_size"> <!-- notice the v-model here -->
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col
        v-for="size in product.size_maps"
        :key="size.id"
        size="6"
        id="product_size"
      >
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="ion-no-margin">
            {{ size.size.text }}
          </ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" :value="size.size.id"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

*then add `selected_size` in data :*

```
  data() {
    return {
      ...
      selected_size: 0
    };
  }
```

*then in method access this selected_size as usual*

```
  methods: {
    addToCart(event) {
      console.log(event);
      // get radio button value here
      console.log(this.selected_size);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the ionic framework, but I think I can see your problem. You need to bind your value of `<ion-radio slot="start" :value="size.size.id"></ion-radio>` to the data-property, as follows: `<ion-radio slot="start" v-model="size.size.id"></ion-radio>` and

```
  data() {
    return {
      size: {
        size: {
          id: ''
        },
      },
    };
  },
```

The key here is to have an initial value as specified by ionic framework. I just added an empty string. You should also set an initial value to the radio-button, as follows:

In your method, you can then just access the value:

```
 methods: {
    addToCart(event) {
      console.log(event);
      // get radio button value here
      console.log(this.size.size.id);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `size.size.id` is in a loop. how do i know which one is selected?

Comment: Well, I figured that if you add the `v-model` in the `ion-radio-group` then it worked. Thanks for your effort though

Comment: I just wanted to edit my answer again to move v-model to the <ion-group/>, after reading a bit through the documentation. Glad to be of help and glad it worked ;)